# Url routing suggestion in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, detailsview

I have an action link in one of my view page

`<%=Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = Model.Id })%>` and redirects me to page  which has a url like this `http://localhost:1985/Materials/Details/2` instead of this i would like to have my url as `http://localhost:1985/Materials/Details/steel` material name instead of Id... Is this possible...... This is my controller action method,

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var material = consRepository.GetMaterial(id);
        return View("Details", material);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I am iterating my json object returned from a jsonresult controller....

```
$.each(data.Results, function() {
            divs += '<a href="/Materials/Details/' + this.Id + '">Details</a>
            &nbsp;<a href="/Materials/Edit/' + this.Id + '">Edit</a></div>';
            });
```

My route look like this,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                           
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                         
                new { controller = "Materials", action = "Index", id = "" } 
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that your URL be

```
http://localhost:1985/Materials/Details/2/Steel
```

This seems to be the way that SO displays their URL's as well.

Your routes would be defined as

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "action with slug", 
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
  new {controller = "Error", action = "NotFound", id = "", slug = ""}
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",                                           
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                         
  new { controller = "Materials", action = "Index", id = "" } 
);
```

In answer to 2nd question in comments, "How do you remove Details from link?"
If you want to remove the ACTION name, so the URL is just `http://site/controler/id/slug`, add the following route BEFORE the action with slug route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "controller with slug", 
  "Materials/{id}/{slug}",
  new {controller = "Materials", action = "Details", id = "", slug = ""}
);
```

The 'slug' which would capture the word steel, would be ignored by the action, because you only want the Id to retrieve the material anyway.

Create a route link instead of an action link, like this

```
<%= Html.RouteLink(material.Name,
      "show with slug", 
      new { controller = "Materials", 
            action = "Details", 
            id = material.Id, 
            slug = Server.HtmlDecode(material.Name).Replace(" ","-")
      }) 
%>
```

I replace spaces in my 'slug's with hyphens so they are not replaced by %20 by the browser.

Your Details ActionResult will remain the same.

Comment: @jason i am iterating json data with jquery and adding the details link via jquery..... Here is what i use `<a href="/Materials/Details/' + this.Id + '/' + this.Mat_Name + '">Details</a>` but this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @jason but if i use `<a href="/Materials/Details/' + this.Id + '">Details</a> it works and i am redirected `http://localhost:1985/Materials/Details/2`

Comment: What do your route mappings look like?  The order of them could be the issue.

Comment: @jason how to strip details from the route?

Comment: Does that additional route give you what you need?

Comment: BTW, I think your routes are backwards.  `Default` route will always match before `action with slug` route.

Comment: You are correct, I added them in the order asked.  Will modify for future clarity :) Thanks.